# Cannot compile Glasgow Haskell Compiler

Tags: compiling, haskell

```
./configure
checking for gfind... no
checking for find... /usr/bin/find
checking for sort... /usr/bin/sort
checking for ghc... no
configure: error: GHC is required unless bootstrapping from .hc files.
256
```

I want to install Glasgow Haskell Compiler, and ./configure asks for GHC. What kind of GHC is it asking for? Global Hadron Collider?
I downloaded the source from http://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_7_6_3

Comment: Unless you have a specific reason to use a different version  its much easier to get it from the software centre or apt-get as already answered by karel.  If you do want to install from source provide a link to where you got it from.

Comment: Is GHC written in Haskell itself?

Comment: It's common practice to write compilers in the language they are supposed to compile. I can only speculate, but I guess this is to show self consistency, by being able to compile the compiler with itself.

Comment: Yes, it is written in Haskell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the results of `apt-cache show ghc` :

```
The Glasgow Haskell Compilation system (GHC) is a compiler for Haskell.
```

To install ghc open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install ghc
```

Create an example Haskell source file, example.hs, containing: `main = putStrLn "Hello, World!"` To compile example.hs change directories using `cd` to the directory containing example.hs and type:

```
ghc -o example example.hs
```

To run the executable:

```
./example
```

Comment: Where is the source of that package?

Comment: If by "source" you mean Software Source, ghc is from the **universe** repository. To enable the universe repository, open the Ubuntu Software Center and browse to _Edit_ -> _Software Sources_ -> _Ubuntu Software_ tab, and make sure there is a check mark next to the second software source in the list which is the universe repository.

Comment: No, I mean the source code of it.

Comment: Enable _Source code_ in the Ubuntu Software Center's Software Sources. It is the last software source in the list. Open the terminal and type: `cd ~/Desktop` (in order to download the source code to your Desktop) and then type `sudo apt-get source ghc`. This will download 4 different files to your Desktop.